# cglib - creating class proxy in OSGi results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, osgi, cglib, bytecode-manipulation, modelmapper

OK so this is some kind of theoretical question for you guys.

I am experimenting with cglib's Enchancer - creating a proxy for a class.
My code is running in a Felix OSGi container.

The hierarchy looks kind of similar to that:

```
// Bundle A;
// Imports-Package: javax.xml.datatype
// Exports-Package: a.foo

package a.foo;
public class Parent {
   protected javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar foo;

   ... -> getter/setter;
}

// Bundle B
// Imports-Package: a.foo
// DOES NOT IMPORT PACKAGE javax.xml.datatype !!!

package b.bar;

import a.foo.Parent;
public class Child extends Parent {
   protected String bar;

   ... -> getter/setter;
}

// Bundle B

// Code extracted from https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/modelmapper/internal/ProxyFactory.java#L59
    public Child enchance() {
         Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
         enhancer.setSuperclass(Child.class);
         enhancer.setUseFactory(true);
         enhancer.setUseCache(true);
         enhancer.setNamingPolicy(NAMING_POLICY);
         enhancer.setCallbackFilter(METHOD_FILTER);
         enhancer.setCallbackTypes(new Class[] { MethodInterceptor.class, NoOp.class });

         try {
             return enhancer.createClass();
         } catch (Throwable t) {
             t.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

From OSGi point of view - the two bundles - Bundle A and Bundle B are fully functional.
The package imports/exports are bnd generated. Although BundleA does not import explicitly the javax.xml.datatype package - I can create instances of Child without any problem.
So far so good.

But when I try to call the enchance() method and create a Child proxy -  cglib throws a NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar

OK, I get this - BundleB's classloader indeed cannot load this class and in fact - cglib's Enchancer seems to be using BundleB's classloader (Child's class type classloader) in order to create the proxy.

On the other hand - for handling modularity the OSGi container is doing the so called classloading delegation - instead of BundleB's classloader, the OSGi runtime delegates the loading of the parent class Parent to BundleA's classloader, which knows how to load all of its fields.
This is why BundleB does not need to explicitly import the javax.xml.datatype package and does not need to know how to load the XMLGregorianCalendar class and still be able to work with Child objects.

I was wondering - isn't such "delegating" approach suitable in the cglib's use case as well?
Please note that I don't know ANYTHING about byte code manipulation and that might sound like a very stupid question to some.
But I really don't understand - why isn't cglib able to delegate loading of the Parent to Parent's own classloader?
Is such mechanism really not available in cglib? Why? Is cglib not used in combination with OSGi? If so then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried combining the OSGi Class Loader Bridge idea that is described here:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/code-generation-with-osgi
... that solves a similar problem with code generation frameworks running within OSGi, with another idea that came to me recently.

The idea is to keep track of class loaders of class types that are found in the parent type hierarchy of the user's type. We can later use these class loaders as fallback for loading types that are otherwise unknown to the Bundle's class loader of the user's type.

We can then tell CGLIB's Enhancer to use this new class loader for resolving.

The idea is presented here:
https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/pull/294

I would love to hear the opinion of experienced OSGi specialists about this though.
But so far this seems to work. 
Until proven wrong, I accept my own answer.

Comment: Since google code is decommissioned the demo project  for the article has been moved to githib: https://github.com/rinswind/enhancer

The demo works with ASM and deliberately proxies only interfaces, because the generated proxy class needs to see only what the target interface sees. So the bridge loader has only has two class loaders -
 the loader of the proxy-generating framework and the loader of the interface.

Comment: To proxy classes the bridge has to search the entire hierarchy of the proxied class. I am not sure there is a search order that can work for all use cases. The OSGi framework's class loading architecture hints one may not exist.

Comment: > To proxy classes the bridge has to search the entire hierarchy of the 
> proxied class.
Correct. This is exactly the approach that I took. The class hierarchy is traversed and the class loaders of each type are kept in a set.
The bridge class loader then uses this set as fallback in findClass()
See: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/pull/294/commits/2ad2b67a2785d9fdcf6aa97820b138cdbe45ea1e#diff-4b8a801f90df21559b0794cd6caec26c

The only drawback is that I can think of is that we keep more ClassLoader references than usually would be required. This seems to work fine so far

Answer (score 0):

The `Child` class does not need to import `javax.xml.datatype` so long as it does not access the `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` field and you are just using the `Child` class in the normal way. However in order to generate a proxy class, CGLib will need to have visibility of the internals of the full inheritance hierarchy including the `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` in order to generate the bytecode for the new type. Therefore an import of the package will be required.

Unfortunately bnd cannot predict that you will be doing bytecode generation on the `Child` class so it does not add the import of `javax.xml.datatype` – it only add the imports required for normal usage.

In general it is a **bad idea** to inherit from a class imported from another bundle. Java inheritance creates a very tight coupling from the subclass to the superclass, which means you are exposed to the internals of the superclass.

To your last question: CGLib is fairly widely used in OSGi for things like mocking objects during testing. It is less used in production because there is nearly always a better solution than bytecode generation, such as proper usage of the service registry.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I stumbled across this fantastic article: https://www.infoq.com/articles/code-generation-with-osgi#anch50634

which explains the problem in details. Seems there is some work in progress already in that area, i.e. the Enhancer project: https://code.google.com/archive/p/enhancer/

Using CGLIB for creating dynamic proxies for classes instead of interfaces is a common requirement. One would have thought that it has a well established solution for OSGi already...

Let's hope that in future java versions we'd get an official API for dynamic proxying for classes

Comment: In my experience, proxy generation is often used outside OSGi as a workaround for the lack of a service registry. It can be used in OSGi but I still tend to think there are better solutions most of the time.